# remove isp-provided dns

Tags: internet, dns

My isp provides a dns service; but unfortunately they do block certain sites.
I would like to use opendns or google; but it seems like it doesn't work.

I have set up a wired connection; given a manual ip and entered opendns-ip's in the nameserver field (all through the gui).
Still url's are being resolved through my ISP.
I have tried to configure the same on my girlfriends laptop (win 7) and I also can't seem to do the setup. My previous computer also was a win 7 and had no problem. (so I believe the problem is 'me')
If it were only one site, i could edit the hosts file; but I prefere to circumvent their whole dns server.

Is there something an isp can do to block the use of other dns-servers than theirs?
Is it possible to re-route the ISP dns to the opendns?

Comment: Note that some ISPs will intercept all DNS requests anyways, whether you've set other ones or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you right-click the Network Manager icon and select Edit Connections. Under IPv4 settings, change the method to Automatic (DHCP) addresses only. Then fill in your preferred DNS nameservers. Please see:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see it there are 3 options:

1. Add your own list of dns tables to the hosts file, its a hassle and will only work for the sites added to the file.
2. Use tor, no more ISP dns but internet will be slower in most cases.
3. Use a VPN, a good one will cost you some money (apox $5 a month)

Other options would be to change ISP, or use a website like http://anonymouse.org/