# Adding DNS' to Ubuntu without editing `etc/resolv.conf`

Tags: networking, dns

The internet on my network works with primary dns `a.b.c.d` and alternate as `e.f.g.h` and everytime I need it to work I need to append `nameserver a.b.c.d` and `nameserver e.f.g.h` to `/etc/resolv.conf`. Isn't there an easier way to do this that probably doesn't involve me doing this when PC restarts, I tried scripts, it works but it just seems as a hack.

Comment: Both of the answers below assume that you are using `/etc/network/interfaces` to configure your connections. I am sure that you are not. By default, you are using Network Manager. Please check here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/422293/remove-isp-provided-dns/422343#422343

Answer (score 2):

Manually add those name servers in your `/etc/network/interfaces` file by inserting the line `dns-nameservers a.b.d.c e.f.g.h` underneath the interface(s) you are using (usually either `eth0` or `wlan0`)

Answer (score 1):

You can either do it by adding the DNS server in the `/etc/network/interfaces` adding the parameter `dns-nameservers` separating each DNS server with a space as following:

```
dns-nameservers 1.2.3.4 5.6.7.8
```

Example:

```
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 10.10.10.254
```

You can also edit the file `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` and edit it the same way you edit the `/etc/resolv.conf`

Example:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 10.10.10.254
search domain.local
```