# Old DNS Settings Keeps Coming Back

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns

Ubuntu 16.04

After moving office I set the DNS settings via Network GUI (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/820873/296989)) to my new values. Internet connection is there, but name resolution seems very slow. My interpretation is, it tries to name-resolve with old settings which times-out after around 5 sec, then tries and succeeds (fast) with new settings.

But whatever I do, the old values are always "in the system" somehow.

After a reboot:

- `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` contains the old DNS addresses
- `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` contains the new DNS addresses
- `/etc/resolv.conf` (`run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`) contains old DNS addresses (from `head`) followed by values in `/run/resolvconf/interface/NetworkManager` (which contains `localhost` and `search`-parameter)

`/etc/network/interfaces` does not contain much:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

I added the new DNS settings into `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` without effect.

The only remedy so far is to manually edit `/etc/resolv.conf` after each boot.

So, question: how can I make Ubuntu forget the old settings (the ones in `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` which are auto-generated).
No `nscd` installed. [This](https://askubuntu.com/a/905619/296989) would seem one way to do it, but I guess there must be a better one.

Not tried option: install dnsmasq and configure as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/163506/100204) (again I think it should be possible without that)

Comment: That message in `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` is used for the file `/etc/resolv.conf`.  If you remove any lines from the `head` file they should not return.  The first line in the `head` file is talking about the `/etc/resolv.conf` file that gets generated when you run `sudo resolvconf -u`.

Comment: @Terrance: I will have a try. The reason I didn't is because that file too has the message `DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND`. So in my thinking whatever I do, next time I have issues this file will contain the old info too.

Comment: @Terrance: It worked. `/etc/resolv.conf` is missing the `base` content but at least the wrong settings are gone. If you want you can write this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/etc/resolv.conf` file is generated from the files stored in the `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d` directory when `sudo resolvconf -u` is ran.

If you make any changes to these files:

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d$ ls -l
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Jun  3  2015 base
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 151 Feb 25  2017 head
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  33 Jun  5  2016 original
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Jun  5  2016 tail
```

The changes will be reflected when you run the `resolvconf -u` command for update.  I actually put my DNS information in the `original` file and I leave all the other files alone:

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d$ cat original 
search local
nameserver 10.0.0.1
```

Then after running the `sudo resolvconf -u` command we can see my changes in my `/etc/resolv.conf` file:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 10.0.0.1
search local
```

**EDIT:** One more thing you may have to check and change is the line `dns=dnsmasq` found in the `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` file.  You can copy and paste the following line to disable using the `dnsmasq` from the NetworkManager.

```
sudo sed -i 's/dns=dnsmasq/#dns=dnsmasq/' /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

After running the above line, reboot the computer for the new changes to take effect.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have your same files, but my /etc/resolv.conf file doesn't get the "original" part. I've always had problems with this overly complex dns structure... I find it Windows-like... if it works, it works, if it breaks, hours of troubleshooting are required and there is no guarantee that a solution will be found.

Comment: @Avio You might need to make sure that NetworkManager is not taking over the DNS either.  Check the edit I just added.  Also, these steps I have only verified in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.