# Can't resolve a domain in Ubuntu, but can in Windows?

Tags: dns, email, smtp, imap

A couple of days ago, I stopped being able to download my email from comcast via pop3.  Every time I ask Thunderbird to get my mail, it says "Failed to connect to mail.comcast.net".  Thing is, I can send mail just fine.  So I thought to myself, why not just try to ping the servers.  This is what I get:

```
procyon@MSI-GS60-6QE:~$ ping mail.comcast.net
ping: mail.comcast.net: Name or service not known
procyon@MSI-GS60-6QE:~$ ping smtp.comcast.net
PING smtp.g.comcast.net (96.114.157.81) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from omta-po.sys.comcast.net (96.114.157.81): icmp_seq=1 ttl=51 time=60.7 ms
64 bytes from omta-po.sys.comcast.net (96.114.157.81): icmp_seq=2 ttl=51 time=69.7 ms
64 bytes from omta-po.sys.comcast.net (96.114.157.81): icmp_seq=3 ttl=51 time=67.2 ms
64 bytes from omta-po.sys.comcast.net (96.114.157.81): icmp_seq=4 ttl=51 time=59.7 ms
```

However, I happen to dual boot this laptop, so I switched over to Windows 10 to try pinging mail.comcast.net from there.  Lo and behold:

```
C:\Users\Scott>ping mail.comcast.net

Pinging imap.ge.xfinity.com [96.117.3.96] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
```

So it's obviously not set up to respond to ping, but the domain DID get resolved (to something else) or so it seems.  I don't know how to begin to debug this sort of problem.  Does anyone out there have any ideas?  Comcast's customer support was useless, as expected.  Thank you.

Comment: Run `nslookup mail.comcast.net` in both Windows and in Ubuntu and see if the `Server:` and `Address:` line right after the command is the same in both.

Comment: Here is how Comcast says to configure thunderbird: [link](https://www.xfinity.com/support/articles/setting-up-thunderbird)

Comment: @TonyB those instructions don't work; that's how the OP already had it configured (albeit for POP).  I had the same problem with both POP and then a few days later after switching to IMAP - Scott Jacabi's answer fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tl;dr: This turned out to be an issue with my /etc/resolv.conf file.

Between LeonidMew's answer and Terrance's comment, I was able to piece this together.  My nslookup for mail was the same as LeonidMew's.  But when I did what Terrance suggested, and tried nslookup in Windows, the Address was pointing to my router at 192.168.0.1. I knew I had seen 127.0.0.53 before when I was Googling around trying to find an answer, and I realized I had seen it in my resolv.conf file.  I edited that file, and changed 127.0.0.53 to 192.169.0.1, and my system was successfully able to find and connect with mail.comcast.net.  Thanks very much for all of your help.

Comment: Depending on what version of Ubuntu you can make that kind of permanent as well.  Ubuntu 16.04 see https://askubuntu.com/questions/988201/old-dns-settings-keeps-coming-back/988373#988373 and for Ubuntu 18.04 I have found to do https://askubuntu.com/a/1057752/231142

Answer (score 1):

Can you reconfigure email client to use imap? Seems imap working fine, with address imap.comcast.net

nslookup for mail:

```
$  nslookup mail.comcast.net
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
mail.comcast.net    canonical name = imap.ge.xfinity.com.
Name:   imap.ge.xfinity.com
Address: 96.118.242.201
Name:   imap.ge.xfinity.com
Address: 96.118.242.237
...
```

Comment: This helped me to find a workaround: I switched to imap.ge.xfinity.com while I was figuring out the method in the other answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

Change from imap.comcast.net to imap.ge.xfinity.com and it will work. Above post shows issue.