# Which upstream nameservers do dnsmasq/NetworkManager use really?

Tags: network-manager, dns, dnsmasq

I'm trying to do some troubleshooting and installing dnscrypt(-proxy) on my Laptop. I want to find out which DNS servers *effectively* are used by my standard Ubuntu installation (w/ NetworkManager and dnsmasq, of course). However I found the configuration of dnsmasq a maze. I couldn't find out which DNS servers it's set to query.

First, I checked `/etc/resolv.conf`, which, of course, is set up to query `127.0.1.1` where dnsmasq-base is listening. Ok, so time to check dnsmasq config for which servers it's set up to query. `/etc/dnsmasq.d/` is empty, though, except for `network-manager` with a single entry: `bind-interfaces`. Not much help there. So I check how NetworkManager calls dnsmasq:

```
$ pgrep -a dnsmasq
1786 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground --no-hosts --bind-interfaces --pid-file=/var/run/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.pid --listen-address=127.0.1.1 --cache-size=0 --conf-file=/dev/null --proxy-dnssec --enable-dbus=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq --conf-dir=/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d
```

Ok so it's not using `/etc/resolv.conf`, it's ignoring `/etc/hosts/`, it's config file is set to `/dev/null` and `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d` is empty, too. So no clues there, either. Must fall back to some defaults or something?

Other files I found:

- `/run/NetworkManager/resolv.conf` says `nameserver 127.0.1.1`
- `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` says `nameserver 127.0.1.1`
- `/etc/resolv.conf` says `nameserver 127.0.1.1`
- `/etc/resolvconf/base` is empty, `./head` only has comments
- `/var/` and `/run/` have no further files named `resolv.conf`

Running `wireshark`, I can see that it's asking my home router for DNS answers (as expected). But where does it get that IP and where do I change it, without using all the other functionality of dnsmasq and NetworkManager (e.g. split DNS for VPN)?

Comment: It's probably getting the DNS address(es) via DHCP. The "functionality" of NetworkManager is provided for exactly that purpose, no? You can edit the connection to use DHCP only for address/gateway info and supply alternate DNS servers there. FYI it shouldn't be necessary to sniff packets - you can use `nmcli` e.g. `nmcli -f 'IP4.DNS' dev show`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found out where that information, after is has ben received via DHCP, is kept:

```
/var/lib/NetworkManager/*lease
```

For *changing* those settings, [refer to NetworkManager's documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Using_the_NetworkManager_Command_Line_Tool_nmcli.html):

```
nmcli con modify my-office my-office ipv4.ignore-auto-dns yes ipv6.ignore-auto-dns yes
nmcli con mod test-lab ipv4.dns "8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4"
nmcli con mod test-lab ipv6.dns "2001:4860:4860::8888 2001:4860:4860::8844"
```

Comment: link broken. But it's not clear how NetworkManager tells dnsmasq the list of upstream DNS servers...

Comment: @bruin See [my answer below](https://askubuntu.com/a/1317343/77109) if you're still curious about that.

Answer (score 2):

*This answer was tested on Ubuntu 16.04 only. Other versions may differ in how they do DNS resolution.*

As you figured out, dnsmasq as managed by NetworkManager does not read any DNS servers from the filesystem. The secret is this flag:

```
--enable-dbus=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq
```

So NetworkManager uses dbus to configure dnsmasq dynamically at runtime. Its dbus interface looks like this:

```
$ sudo dbus-send --system --type=method_call --print-reply \
    --dest=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq \
    /uk/org/thekelleys/dnsmasq \
    org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable.Introspect
method return time=1613637106.507949 sender=:1.16 -> destination=:1.49 serial=11 reply_serial=2
   string "<!DOCTYPE node PUBLIC "-//freedesktop//DTD D-BUS Object Introspection 1.0//EN"
"http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/dbus/1.0/introspect.dtd">
<node name="/uk/org/thekelleys/dnsmasq">
  <interface name="org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable">
    <method name="Introspect">
      <arg name="data" direction="out" type="s"/>
    </method>
  </interface>
  <interface name="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq">
    <method name="ClearCache">
    </method>
    <method name="GetVersion">
      <arg name="version" direction="out" type="s"/>
    </method>
    <method name="GetLoopServers">
      <arg name="server" direction="out" type="as"/>
    </method>
    <method name="SetServers">
      <arg name="servers" direction="in" type="av"/>
    </method>
    <method name="SetDomainServers">
      <arg name="servers" direction="in" type="as"/>
    </method>
    <method name="SetServersEx">
      <arg name="servers" direction="in" type="aas"/>
    </method>
    <method name="SetFilterWin2KOption">
      <arg name="filterwin2k" direction="in" type="b"/>
    </method>
    <method name="SetBogusPrivOption">
      <arg name="boguspriv" direction="in" type="b"/>
    </method>
    <signal name="DhcpLeaseAdded">
      <arg name="ipaddr" type="s"/>
      <arg name="hwaddr" type="s"/>
      <arg name="hostname" type="s"/>
    </signal>
    <signal name="DhcpLeaseDeleted">
      <arg name="ipaddr" type="s"/>
      <arg name="hwaddr" type="s"/>
      <arg name="hostname" type="s"/>
    </signal>
    <signal name="DhcpLeaseUpdated">
      <arg name="ipaddr" type="s"/>
      <arg name="hwaddr" type="s"/>
      <arg name="hostname" type="s"/>
    </signal>
    <method name="AddDhcpLease">
       <arg name="ipaddr" type="s"/>
       <arg name="hwaddr" type="s"/>
       <arg name="hostname" type="ay"/>
       <arg name="clid" type="ay"/>
       <arg name="lease_duration" type="u"/>
       <arg name="ia_id" type="u"/>
       <arg name="is_temporary" type="b"/>
    </method>
    <method name="DeleteDhcpLease">
       <arg name="ipaddr" type="s"/>
       <arg name="success" type="b" direction="out"/>
    </method>
  </interface>
</node>
"
```

So there is `SetServers`, which NetworkManager presumably uses, and `GetLoopServers`, but not `GetServers`.

The second best thing we can do is send SIGUSR1 to dnsmasq. This makes it dump a status report to syslog containing statistics for each server:

```
$ sudo kill -USR1 $(pgrep dnsmasq)
$ sudo tail /var/log/syslog
...
... dnsmasq[927]: server 192.168.1.1#53: queries sent 2, retried or failed 0
... dnsmasq[927]: server 1.1.1.1#53: queries sent 2, retried or failed 0
... dnsmasq[927]: server 8.8.8.8#53: queries sent 25, retried or failed 0
```

I'm not sure whether these are only the servers currently in use, or whether the list also contains ones that have since been removed. But as far as I know, this is the most authoritative answer we can get.

Answer (score 0):

We know that you obtain your IP address, DNS nameservers, etc. from a DHCP transaction with your router, switch or other access point. If yours was a static address, you would have been required to specify the DNS nameservers and you'd therefor already know the DNS servers effectively being used.

In a DHCP transaction, the DNS nameservers in the router are transferred to your connection. In fact, they may come, in turn, from the modem or internet appliance provided by your internet service provider.

You can probably specify the nameservers you prefer by accessing the administration pages of the router like this.[image]

As well, you can direct Network Manager to use preferred nameservers, like this: [remove isp-provided dns](https://askubuntu.com/questions/422293/remove-isp-provided-dns/422343#422343)

Since the DNS nameservers vary by connection; that is, you will receive a different DNS nameserver connected at work from the nameserver connected at home, the provided numbers are shown in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/foo where foo is the name of the connection. For instance, one of my connections is *Wired Connection 1* and it reports, among other entries:

```
[ipv4]
dns=8.8.8.8;8.8.4.4;
dns-search=
ignore-auto-dns=true
method=auto
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, I'm already aware of how the router sends those information to my pc as part of dhcp. My question is more about the configuration file in which dnsmasq stores that information after dhcpcd received it. I.e. where is the resolved.conf file (or similiar) that does not point to 127.0.1.1 (dnsmasq) but to the IP my router gave me for DNS (192.168.178.1)

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few minutes.

Comment: `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` is empty for me

Comment: Is Network Manager running on your system? `ps aux | grep -i network` Your response implies that you have *never* had any connection.